# macOS Mojave suddenly changes focus to a Chrome window

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, google-chrome

For some reason, when I am working on my MacBook Pro (15", 2018) either typing or doing whatever, the focus changes to a specific Chrome window for no apparent reason. The window that the focus goes to, does not have any particular website opened.

The software installed is pretty much the same as my old MacBook Pro (15", Mid 2015). They are both running macOS Mojave, but this doesn't happen in my old MacBook.

The computer works mainly with the lid closed, connected to a LCD via Thunderbolt using Magic Keyboard and Magic Trackpad for input. The focus switch happens randomly, it even happens when my hands are off the keyboard and trackpad (laptop and remote ones).

This is getting really annoying. Has this ever happened to anyone else? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: It appears that some process/app/extension is stealing focus. Are you sure both your MacBooks have the apps/extensions installed? If not, you can start debugging by isolating the apps/extensions that are only installed on your newer MacBook.

Comment: Have you found your problem, I'm experiencing exactly the same here...

Comment: I'm also having the issue. Intermittently throughout the day, my most recent Chrome tab will steal focus away from whatever other app I'm using. Disabling Chrome extensions doesn't appear to solve it.